# Straight JS to open a pop up window on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I need to do a form post to a php page with radio button questions to show poll results on a php page.

For some reason none of the variables are being passed in as $_POST or $_GET; I've tried both. On the php page I did

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_GET);
?>
```

In return I get:

```
Array ( ) Array ( )
```

Here is my actual form call.

```
<form action="poll_vote.php" method="post" target="blank" onsubmit="window.open('poll_vote.php', '_blank', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=300,width=400,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');return true\
;">
```

I'm open to use JQuery or JS if anyone knows what I can do to fix why the variables aren't being passed in although I specified `method="post"`

Comment: your `<form>` tag has errors. Replace `<form action="poll_vote.php" method="post" target="blank" onsubmit="window.open('poll_vote.php', '_blank', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=300,width=400,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');return true\
;">` with `<form action="poll_vote.php" method="post" target="blank" onsubmit="window.open('poll_vote.php', '_blank', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=300,width=400,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');return true;">`

Comment: @Lal: I'm still getting 0 vars when I submit-- I changed it to the way you described here.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening a window but you aren't posting there, that's why your variables aren't being passed. Keep "target=blank" part and remove "onsubmit" one.

Comment: if I remove the onsubmit will it open a pop-up window?

Comment: How can I submit-- have a pop-up windows open submitting all the html values in the <form> ?